# How do import kivy in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I've installed Kivy.....a lot of times.

I'm in VS Code and it shows in Libraries but I can't seem to figure out how to import.

Getting `kivy module does not exist` error.

Can run a `.py` file with just `import kivy` in the terminal with success.

Cannot run kivy built-in example from terminal.   `ErrNo2`

[image: kivy VS Code library]

Comment: its because you might be running vscode in sandbox so you need to install kivy via pip in vscode terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening python environment as current project. It's not recommended to do so, and we usually open a folder and select the python environment as interpreter.

Turn back to your question, make sure you've selected the opened environment as interpreter. Open Command Palette, click **Python: Select intepreter** then enter interpreter path. It will pop up a folder explorer, choose your `current opened Scripts\python.exe`, then you can `import kivy` successfully:

[image]

More information please view [Python Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) and [Python Environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Thanks! Still learning, could not figure out how to do that.  Worked great.